# Doctrine 2 DQL: Can I combine these queries into 1

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to combine these queries into 1

```
# Get completed todos
SELECT COUNT(t.id) from Application\Models\Todos t 
WHERE t.parent IS NULL 
AND t.todoList.project = :proj
AND t.completedOn IS NOT NULL

# Get total todos
SELECT COUNT(t.id) from Application\Models\Todos t
WHERE t.parent IS NULL 
AND t.todoList.project = :proj
```

- A Project have Lists
- A List have Todos
- A Todo can have 1 level of children todo - In my queries, I was querying for top level todos
- A Todo have completedOn, dueOn

In another function, I want to get

- total number of tasks belonging to you & the project
- total number of completed tasks belonging to you & the project
- total number of incompleted tasks due today belonging to you & the project

Do I need to do it in separate queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a flag INT completed 1/0 then yes, using a SUM and a COUNT, but in this case i dont think its possible.

Comment: my `completedOn` is nullable so does that mean I can `COUNT(completedOn)`? `NULLs` don't count right? I havent tested it tho. If it isn't possible would you do multiple SQL queries or select all rows + required columns and count on application (PHP)?